# Handle a user request when a server is off (Volley)

Tags: android, null, android-volley, is-empty

I am developing a android application for Client Server communication using Volley,when server is in off state user cant receive the response, i want to handle volley request from when server is off state any help me to handle this..

```
         StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            t_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
Toast.make...(...,response,..).show();
            if (response.toString().isEmpty()) {
                ViewDialog1 alert = new ViewDialog1();
                alert.showDialog(MainActivity.this, "Network Error", R.drawable.network_error);

            }
            if (response == null) {
                ViewDialog1 alert = new ViewDialog1();
                alert.showDialog(MainActivity.this, "Network Error", R.drawable.network_error);
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(response.toString())) {
                ViewDialog1 alert = new ViewDialog1();
                alert.showDialog(MainActivity.this, "Network Error", R.drawable.network_error);
            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse ( final VolleyError error){
            if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {

                ViewDialog1 alert = new ViewDialog1();
                alert.showDialog(MainActivity.this, "Network Error", R.drawable.network_error);
            }
        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
            //TODO
        } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
            //TODO
        } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
            //TODO
        } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
            //TODO
        }

        }
```

when the server is of no alert shows. only toast will appear with empty

how can I handle user request when the server off or any variable chnage from webservice ?

Comment: I am checking Network for all API call. If Network Enable then hit the server. Otherwise, show a Message to the user. Like "No internet connection"

Comment: but it is different , I also check Network when  API call.